# Why am I getting an error code 500 on patch request for Express backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, express

My angular frontend is sending a patch request to my express backend and all routes are working except for my patch routes. The error is: Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided. Do I need to do something with the results parameter in the arrow functions of the updateQuote and updatePhrase functions in the backend service?

```
//quotes.service.ts (angular)

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Quote } from '../models/quote.model';
import { Phrase } from '../models/phrase.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuotesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getQuotes(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/quotes');
  }

  postQuote(quote: Array<Quote | Phrase>) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/quotes', quote).subscribe((data) => {
    });
  }

  deleteQuote(quoteid: any) {
    return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:3000/quotes/delete/${quoteid}`);
  }

  updateQuote(quoteid: any, payload: any) {
    return this.http.patch(`http://localhost:3000/quotes/update/${quoteid}`, payload);
  }

}
```

```
//quotes.controller.js (express)

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const db = require('../services/quotes.service')

router.get('/', db.getQuotes);
router.get('/phrases', db.getPhrases);
router.post('/', db.createQuote);
router.delete('/delete/:quoteid', db.deleteQuote);
router.patch('/update/:quoteid', db.updateQuote);
router.patch('/phrases/update/:phraseid', db.updatePhrase);

module.exports = router;
```

```
//quotes.service.js (express)

const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'leaquotesapp',
  password: 'password',
  port: 5432,
});

const getQuotes = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM quotes ORDER BY quoteid ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  });
}

const getPhrases = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM phrases ORDER BY phraseid ASC', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
  });
}

const createQuote = (request, response) => {
  let quote = request.body[0];

  pool.query(`INSERT INTO quotes (title, context, speakers) 
    VALUES ('${quote.title}', '${quote.context}', '${quote.speakers}') RETURNING quoteid`, (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
      throw error;
    }

    //Insert phrases...
    let quoteid = results.rows[0].quoteid;

    for(let i = 1; i < request.body.length; i++) {
      request.body[i].quoteid = quoteid;
      createPhrase(request.body[i]);
    }

    response.status(201).send();
  });
}

function createPhrase(phrase) {
  pool.query(`INSERT INTO phrases (sequence, speaker, text, quoteid) 
  VALUES (${phrase.sequence}, '${phrase.speaker}', '${phrase.text}', ${phrase.quoteid})`, (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  });
}

const deleteQuote = (request, response) => {
  let quoteid = request.params.quoteid;

  pool.query(`DELETE FROM quotes WHERE quoteid = ${quoteid}`, (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  });

  pool.query(`DELETE FROM phrases WHERE quoteid = ${quoteid}`, (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  });

  response.status(200).json({'Delete': 'Success'});
}

const updateQuote = (request, response) => {
  let quoteid = request.params.quoteid;
  let column = request.body.keys[0];
  let value = request.body.column;

  pool.query(`UPDATE quotes SET ${column} = ${value} WHERE quoteid = ${quoteid}`, (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  });

  response.status(200).json({'Update': 'Success'});
}

const updatePhrase = (request, response) => {
  let phraseid = request.params.quoteid;
  let column = request.body.keys[0];
  let value = request.body.column;

  pool.query(`UPDATE phrases SET ${column} = ${value} WHERE phraseid = ${phraseid}`, (error, results) => {
    if(error) {
      throw error;
    }
  });

  response.status(200).json({'Update': 'Success'}); 
}

module.exports = {
  getQuotes,
  getPhrases,
  createQuote,
  deleteQuote,
  updateQuote,
  updatePhrase
}
```

Comment: Does it work from REST client (Postman etc.) ?

Comment: @robert No, I get the same error

Comment: what is your payload?

Comment: It's a javascript object in the form { 'key': 'value' } with the key being either 'title' or 'context' depending on which quote attribute wants to be changed

Comment: Maybe you have in `value` field something that you DB doesn't like, try to execute your update query with data you send

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your app.js file. Maybe you have not set the view engine or the view engine used is not configured well and that is what causing the error.

Your app.js file would reveal more.

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question, if you are looking for extra information, instead of answering, please comment down on the question itself.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32776834)